# why does my break statement breaks out of the entire program?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, break

The `break;` statement in my Exception clause stops the entire program if my have improper input to the JOptionPane, it would not execute what I have after the catch block, why is that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Customer forrest = new Customer("Forrest Grump", 1,
                "42 New Street, New York, New York");
        Customer random = new Customer("Random Name", 2,
                "44 New Street, New York, New York");
        Customer customer[] = { null, forrest, random };
        int whichOption = 1;
        int id = 0;
        char action = ' ';
        char accSrc = ' ';
        char accDest = ' ';
        double amount = 0;
        BankAccount src = null;
        do {

            try{
            // process JOptionPane input information
            String input = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please enter your transaction information: ");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
            id = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
            action = Character.toUpperCase((s.next().charAt(0)));

            if (action == 'T') {
                amount = s.nextDouble();
                accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
                accDest = s.next().charAt(0);
            } else if (action == 'G' || action == 'I') {
                accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
            } else {
                // if D,W
                amount = s.nextDouble();
                accSrc = s.next().charAt(0);
            }

            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                break;
            }
            // taking action accordingly (T)ransfer, (D)eposit, (W)ithdraw, (I)nterest
            if (action == 'T') {

                (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).transfer(amount,
                        customer[id].getAccount(accDest));
            } else if (action == 'G') {
                System.out.println("The current balance on your " + accSrc
                        + " account is "
                        + customer[id].getAccount(accSrc).getBalance() + "\n");
            } else if (action == 'D') {
                (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).deposit(amount);
                //You have successfully depositted $xx.xx
            } else if (action == 'W') {
                (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).withdraw(amount);
            } else if (action == 'I') {
                (customer[id].getAccount(accSrc)).computeInterest();
            }
            whichOption = JOptionPane
                    .showConfirmDialog(null , "Do you want to continue?");

            System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
                    + " auto account is " + customer[id].A.balance);
            System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
                    + " savings account is " + customer[id].S.balance);
            System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
                    + " checkings account is " + customer[id].C.balance);
            System.out.println("The balance on " + customer[id].getName()
                    + " loan account is " + customer[id].L.balance + "\n");

        } while (whichOption == 0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you wish to `continue`, not `break`. See the difference here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

`continue` tells the loops to skip all of the following statements in the loop body and return to the top of the loop body, recheck the condition, and then continue looping normally from there.

`break` tells the loop to end immediately, ignoring any further instructions in the loop body.

Comment: if in the exception block, i want to restart the program, rather than restarting the loop, what code should i use to relaunch the `main()`?

Comment: a quick fix would be to replace `break;` with `this.main(args); System.exit(0);`. You may actually only need `main(args); System.exit(0);`

Comment: if we call `main(args)` again wouldn't that become recursion? so if the user provided invalid input too many times wouldn't we get a stackoverflow error?

Comment: that is an accurate assessment of the recursive nature involved in the "quick fix" I mentioned. See my **second** answer for a restructuring of `main` to include a helper method.

Comment: oic, looks like this is the only way to prevent SO...thank you!

Answer (score 3):

because using `break` you are jumping out of the loop (and that is the end of your program), if you wish to execute after catch block part, simply remove `break;`

---

**See**

- [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: looks like i unexpectedly stopped the program, what if i want to stop the program where there's no loop, what should I put in the exception block to stop the program?

Comment: depends on how you want to quit it, common way is to use `System.exit()`

Comment: thank you, it works!!! if in the exception block, i want to restart the program, what code should i use to relaunch the `main()`?

Comment: just put this whole code in another method and call it, use main as a launcher

Comment: so it's not possible to relaunch `main()`?

Answer (score 0):

`break` escapes from the enclosing loop, which in your case means the end of main...

Answer (score 0):

You're `break`ing out of the loop and there's nothing left after the loop in your `main` method. If you want to continue looping, replace the `break;` with `continue;`.

Comment: if in the exception block, i want to restart the program, rather than restarting the loop, what code should i use to relaunch the `main()`?

Comment: call main again... replace `break;` with `main(args);`

Comment: wouldn't that become recursion? if the user provided invalid input too many times wouldn't we get a stackoverflow error?